# Issues sending XML with special characters : ' & - /

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, utf-8, xml-parsing

I am passing Session values to XML in code behind of my Asp.Net    Project and passing it to SP in SQL server.

One of the XML tag `<stMC></stMC>` is not ignoring special characters 
      like  ' & - / etc.

There is no xml parsing error.
Just when I pass text with special char. I get no data from sp.
So I thought it may be because of special characters.

Is there any way I can make XML ignore special characters in tag? 
  If any other way please suggest .

Problem example :

```
<root>
   <header>
      <stNo>1100</stNo>
      <stMC>Test's</stMC>
   </header>
</root>
```

In `<stMC>` tag , ' (apostrophe is ending my XML).

Please suggest how to ignore special characters.

Comment: It is unclear how these characters break things. Do you get invalid XML (eg. unescaped `&` characters) or does the XML parsing process break when it encounters `'`? Note that your example is perfectly valid XML – except for the closing tag mismatch (`</MC>` instead of `</stMC>`), which is probably a typo in the post only.

Comment: How can I allow use of special characters in my XML tags.
whenever I select ddl text containing special characters , it fails my db operation.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Hi lenz , thanks for reply.
I did not get any invalid xml error or anything like that I just don't get any response from SP.
So I manually run sp like below 
exec usp_GetDetails  '<root>
  <header>
    <stMC>Chico's VF Test</stMC>
    <inPageNo>1</inPageNo>
    <inPageSize>10</inPageSize>
  </header>
</root>'
AT Chico's opostrophe it gives red color that is sp is ending.

WHat you suggested is a typo error by me  <stMC>Test's</MC>
.

Comment: Please update your question with that new information, it's unreadable and too much hidden as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:-

[**List of XML and HTML character entity references**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

That article mentioned the following five predefined XML entities:

```
  quot  " 
  amp   &
  apos  '
  lt    <
  gt    >
```